# XSL sum values after for each

Tags: xml

you will see I have the following code and I need to do a for each to show later in a table the results.
so far i have this, but what i want is to show the total results, can anyone help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "record.xsl"?>
<records>
<record>
    <dateRep>30/03/2020</dateRep>
    <day>30</day>
    <month>3</month>
    <year>2020</year>
    <cases>8</cases>
    <deaths>1</deaths>
    <countriesAndTerritories>Afghanistan</countriesAndTerritories>
    <geoId>AF</geoId>
    <countryterritoryCode>AFG</countryterritoryCode>
    <popData2018>37172386</popData2018>
</record>
<record>
    <dateRep>29/03/2020</dateRep>
    <day>29</day>
    <month>3</month>
    <year>2020</year>
    <cases>15</cases>
    <deaths>1</deaths>
    <countriesAndTerritories>Afghanistan</countriesAndTerritories>
    <geoId>AF</geoId>
    <countryterritoryCode>AFG</countryterritoryCode>
    <popData2018>37172386</popData2018>
</record>
<record>
    <dateRep>28/03/2020</dateRep>
    <day>28</day>
    <month>3</month>
    <year>2020</year>
    <cases>16</cases>
    <deaths>1</deaths>
    <countriesAndTerritories>Afghanistan</countriesAndTerritories>
    <geoId>AF</geoId>
    <countryterritoryCode>AFG</countryterritoryCode>
    <popData2018>37172386</popData2018>
</record>
<records>
```

XSL --I want to show a single table with the total results for each

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">   

<xsl:template match = "/">  

  <html> 
     <body> 
        <h2>Datos Mundiales del Coronavirus</h2> 

        <table border = "1"> 
           <tr bgcolor = "#9acd32"> 
              <th>Pais</th> 
              <th>Código Pais</th> 
              <th>Fecha</th> 
              <th>Casos</th> 
              <th>Muertes</th>
              <th>Población</th> 
           </tr> 



           <xsl:for-each select="records/record"> 
              <tr> 
                 <td><xsl:value-of select = "countriesAndTerritories"/></td>
                 <td><xsl:value-of select = "geoId"/></td> 
                 <td><xsl:value-of select = "dateRep"/></td> 
                 <td><xsl:value-of select = "cases"/></td> 
                 <td><xsl:value-of select = "deaths"/></td> 
                 <td><xsl:value-of select = "popData2018"/></td>                        
              </tr> 
           </xsl:for-each> 

        </table> 
     </body> 
  </html> 
</xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is for an exercise and I don't have much information on how to make variables in the for each loop and be able to sum them after this, if someone could help me it would be great.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is a functional language, so you don't do this the way you would in a procedural language with defined order of execution and mutable variables.

Just add logic to compute the totals at the end:

```
      <tr> 
         ...
         <td><xsl:value-of select = "sum(record/records/cases)"/></td> 
         <td><xsl:value-of select = "sum(record/records/deaths)"/></td> 
         ...                 
      </tr>
```